# configure hive with hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, ubuntu-12.04

I have configured hadoop 2.2.0 as single node cluster ( was able to run example jar)

Now I need to make hive perform queries using this hadoop

should I set

```
mapred.job.tracker
```

to

```
yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address
```

property?

tried so, but can't see the data loaded into hive tables in hdfs

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to add a comment, so trying to help via an answer.

1. What are the daemons currently running for Hadoop? Use ps -eaf |
   grep "java" to check.
2. Do you see the JobTracker running or the ResourceManager?

Also, can you elaborate on the steps you performed to install Hive?

I have screen cast, [Installing Apache Hive](http://www.hadoopscreencasts.com/episodes/4) that walks you through installing Hive. Next, you can follow my blog post [Apache Hive - Getting Started](http://www.rohitmenon.com/index.php/apache-hive-getting-started/). Hope this helps.